# Can VSCode TextDocument.fileName property be an empty string or null?

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-api

Visual Studio Code API extensively uses `TextDocument` abstraction:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextDocument
As an author of a VSCode extension, I would like to know if it is possible for `TextDocument` `fileName` property to be an empty string or null/undefined? And if so in which cases it could be empty?

Comment: I believe the file name is empty for new text documents until the user saved it. After that it always has a file name.

Comment: Empty new docs have `Untitled-X` fileName where X is an integer that increments with each new empty doc starting from 1. I've never seen a doc with an empty fileName so far but I am worrying that not handling such files would exclude some potentially important class of VSCode documents.